# Failed queries does not cause data factory activity to fail

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm loading data every hour from a csv file in Azure Data Lake Store into a table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse. The load is performed by a SqlServerStoredProcedure data factory activity and the input dataset is an external table on top of the csv file(s) received in the latest hour. In the data factory activity monitor everything is green (Ready) and it seems the data is loaded into the target table as expected, BUT in the query activity monitor for SQL DW I see a lot of Failed queries. When I look at the query text it looks like it is the insert statement executed by the SqlServerStoredProcedure activity that has failed, but in that case I would assume that the data factory activity would fail. Right?

Answer (score 0):

this does not sound like a normal behavior. It might be related to the stored procedure logic and how the error was thrown from that stored procedure. Is it possible you can share the ADF Activity RunID so we can help you check from ADF backend? You can reach out to me by s h e n g c at m i c r o s o f t dot com. 
Thank you.